# How do i Cascade my dropdowns in MudBlazor Given the @onchange doesn't work

Tags: mudblazor

I am making a form With Cascaded dropdowns I got the logic working using the select component of blazor but when I try to use it on mudselect the @onchange function doesn't fire I have no idea how to use the Valuechanged EventCallback of the same so I am stuck on what to do. if anyone has done cascading in Mudblazor I am intrigued by how it was done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure this answers your problem but due to a lack of details this is the first step. As you found out MudSelect offers the `ValueChanged` callback that you can hook into. You write your own method that the component shall call when the value changes. In the sample below that's `void OnBeverageChanged()`. Now you reference it as parameter of MudSelect.

You can run the code below with [Try MudBlazor](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cEwQEgQgnIFGMohh) and experiment with it until you have what you need.

```xml
<MudSelect T="string" Label="Coffee" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" ValueChanged=OnBeverageChanged>
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Cappuccino")" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Cafe Latte")" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Espresso")" />
</MudSelect>
<MudText>
How many times did you change your beverage ... do you know it's: @TimesChanged
</MudText>
```

```cs
@code {
    public class Pizza
    {
        public Pizza(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public readonly string Name;

        // Note: this is important so the MudSelect can compare pizzas
        public override bool Equals(object o) {
            var other = o as Pizza;
            return other?.Name==Name;
        }

        // Note: this is important too!
        public override int GetHashCode() => Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;

        // Implement this for the Pizza to display correctly in MudSelect
        public override string ToString() => Name;
    }

    private int TimesChanged = 0;

    private void OnBeverageChanged()
    {
        TimesChanged++;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```